# Container test_0_4cb91f00 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, chatbot

I'm trying to deploy Echo bot from microsoft samples of botframework to azure web app (python) and Whenever i try to test it after a successful deployment an error appears says

Initiating warmup request to container test_0_fea5f125 for site test
2023-11-09T09:25:00.574Z ERROR - Container test_0_fea5f125 for site test has exited, failing site start
2023-11-09T09:25:00.607Z ERROR - Container test_0_fea5f125 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

I've tried to deploy the .net Echo bot to azure web app and it's working perfectly but the python one doesn't, and i tried to add the WEBSITES_PORT = 8000 in azure web app configuration and still got the same error.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1l8j.png]

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the below steps to create and deploy Echo Bot to Azure App Service.**

- Referred [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python%2Cvs) and created an **Echo Bot application** with the command:

```
cookiecutter https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/releases/download/Templates/echo.zip
```

**Bot Framework Emulator response in local:**

[image]

- **Modify the below code in **app.py****

```py
app = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
app.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        web.run_app(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

**Instead, add the below code** taken from [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60509194/19991670).

- Thanks **@jackygeee** for the code:

```py
def init_func(argv):
    APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
    APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    return APP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = init_func(None)

    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

### **UPDATED SOLUTION:**

**requirements.txt:**

```
botbuilder-integration-aiohttp>=4.14.0
aiohttp
botbuilder-core
botbuilder-schema
```

- Create and activate virtual environment in local by running the below commands:

```
python -m venv env
env\Scripts\activate
```

[image]

---

- Create **Azure Bot** and **Azure App Service**:
- Go to `Azure Bot=> Configuration`, paste your web app's URL by adding `/api/messages`(https://<webapp_name>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages) in the **Messaging EndPoint.**
- Copy `Microsoft App ID` value.
- Click on **Manage Password** in the configuration, create new secret and copy its value (which will be used as `Microsoft App password` in the code).

[image]

- Created a **secret** to use its **value** as my **Application password**:

[image]

- Go to **Config.py** in your **Echo Bot** project and paste the ***App_ID*** and ***App_Password*** which were copied as mentioned above.

```py
import os
class DefaultConfig:
    """ Bot Configuration """

    PORT = 3978
    APP_ID = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppId", "<Your_App_ID>")
    APP_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppPassword", "<Your_App-Password")
```

- **Deploy the application to Azure App Service:**

[image]

**After deploying the application to Azure:**

- Navigate to your `web app=>Settings=> Configuration =>General Settings=> Startup Command`, add the command:

```
python3 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func
```

[image]

- Go to your **Azure Bot =>Settings=>Test in Web Chat** and test the chat:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I did exactly this and am now receiving this error:

`2023-11-14T03:30:04.570355720Z /opt/python/3/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'aiohttp.web' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp')`


The application deploys correctly but when running the error above appears and the bot does not respond to any messages.

Comment: Add `botbuilder-integration-aiohttp>=4.14.0`
`aiohttp`
`botbuilder-core`
`botbuilder-schema` in `requirements.txt` and install the modules by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: @7Leven, check the updated solution.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my `requirements.txt`, although I'm not sure how to leverage your advice with the virtual environment because I'm just deploying my azure bot directly using `az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $appName --src $srcPath`. I have my application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` set to `true` as well, so it should install the pip requirements at deployment. I am still receiving the error I posted above: `(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp')`

Comment: Did you install those dependencies locally?

Comment: Yes but, my error is occurring remotely in my azure web app. My bot runs fine in my local emulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255934/discussion-between-7leven-and-pravallika-kv).

Comment: the documentation doesn't mention this at all (not that I am surprised but it is a pain always )

Comment: Have followed these steps exactly as mentioned, however, I am getting the following error: python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.11.so.1.0

Comment: @PravallikaKV Why are we adding the custom startup script after deployment?

Comment: This is the correct solution. Tested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying using a zip file, when creating the ZIP package for deployment, don't include the root directory, but only the files and directories in it. It took me a while to deploy my echo bot, and the error was due the way I was creating the zip file. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package

```
# Bash
zip -r <file-name>.zip .

# PowerShell
Compress-Archive -Path * -DestinationPath <file-name>.zip
```