# Azure ChatBot Running With Python on an Azure WebApp Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, chatbot

I am trying to run this:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot

This runs perfectly fine locally

I changed the default port to 8000 and set the necessary variables in the WebApp:
[image]

I also added the app registration ID/Password into the WebApp variables and config.py file.

This allows the app to (seemingly) run fine on the webapp, however the chatbot cannot connect and gets the below errors:

[image]

Going to the site https://quinntest.azurewebsites.net/ gives a 500

[image]

[image]

Here is the webapp config:

[image]

[image]

Has anyone experienced this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Follow below steps to connect and test Azure Bot:**

**app.py:**

I have added  `init_func()` in the `app.py` code.

```py
import sys
import traceback
from datetime import datetime

from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web import Request, Response, json_response
from botbuilder.core import (BotFrameworkAdapter, BotFrameworkAdapterSettings,
                             TurnContext)
from botbuilder.core.integration import aiohttp_error_middleware
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes

from bot import MyBot
from config import DefaultConfig

CONFIG = DefaultConfig()

SETTINGS = BotFrameworkAdapterSettings(CONFIG.APP_ID, CONFIG.APP_PASSWORD)
ADAPTER = BotFrameworkAdapter(SETTINGS)


async def on_error(context: TurnContext, error: Exception):

    print(f"\n [on_turn_error] unhandled error: {error}", file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exc()

    await context.send_activity("The bot encountered an error or bug.")
    await context.send_activity(
        "To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code."
    )

    if context.activity.channel_id == "emulator":

        trace_activity = Activity(
            label="TurnError",
            name="on_turn_error Trace",
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            type=ActivityTypes.trace,
            value=f"{error}",
            value_type="https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
        )
        
        await context.send_activity(trace_activity)

ADAPTER.on_turn_error = on_error

BOT = MyBot()

async def messages(req: Request) -> Response:

    if "application/json" in req.headers["Content-Type"]:
        body = await req.json()
    else:
        return Response(status=415)

    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)
    auth_header = req.headers["Authorization"] if "Authorization" in req.headers else ""

    response = await ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, BOT.on_turn)
    if response:
        return json_response(data=response.body, status=response.status)
    return Response(status=201)

# Modifying the below code

def init_func(argv):
    APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
    APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    return APP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = init_func(None)

    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

- Navigate to  **Config.py** code  in your **Echo Bot**  project and paste  **App_ID**_  and  ***App_Password***  which were copied from Azure Bot.

```py
import os
class DefaultConfig:
    """ Bot Configuration """

    PORT = 3978
    APP_ID = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppId", "<Your_App_ID>")
    APP_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppPassword", "<Your_App-Password>")
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
botbuilder-integration-aiohttp>=4.14.0
aiohttp
botbuilder-core
botbuilder-schema
```

- **Deploy the application to Azure App Service.**
- Open your Azure Bot, add the Azure App Service's URL by adding */api/messages*`(https://<webapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages)` in the `Settings=>Configuration=>Messaging Endpoint`.

[image]

- Navigate to  `Azure App Service=>Configuration=>General Settings=>Startup Command`, use the command  `python3 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func` to run the application.

[image]

- Go to  **Azure Bot=>Test in Web chat**  to test the connection:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/2Yymb0y.png]

Comment: Thank you for this attempt. It still does not work unfortunately
2024-01-12T16:28:37.341Z ERROR - Container quinntest_0_f3d5ec13 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-01-12T16:28:37.375Z INFO  - Stopping site quinntest because it failed during startup.

Comment: Create a new App Service and deploy your app again and check if it works.

Comment: 2024-01-15T14:24:15.034163476Z /opt/python/3/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'aiohttp.web' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp')

Comment: Did you add `aiohttp` module in `requirements. txt`?

Comment: yes I did, my requirements file looks the same as yours above

Comment: Run your application locally once and check if it's working as expected

Comment: Yes it is working fine locally

Comment: Now deploy and test it again.

Comment: @QuinnFavo, Did you deploy again and check if it works.

Comment: It still does not work. I have spent hours trying to deploy the basic echo bot but it fails to run.

Comment: Check if this [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77458128/19991670) & [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77478851/19991670) helps.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with https, by default the Chatbot only allows an HTTPS URL however the Python code only allows http, is there a way around this? I am trying to set up https for the code but it isn't working